# How to recursively get a list of all children in a nested object?

Tags: javascript, recursion

Suppose I have a class that can hold other instances of itself:

```
function Thing() {
    this.subThings = [];
}
```

And I add `n` `subThings` to the top thing:

```
var rootThing = new Thing();

rootThing.subThings.push(new Thing());
rootThing.subThings.push(new Thing());
rootThing.subThings.push(new Thing());
```

And then I add `n` `subThings` to some of the `rootThing`'s `subThings`:

```
rootThing.subThings[0].subThings.push(new Thing());
rootThing.subThings[0].subThings.push(new Thing());
rootThing.subThings[0].subThings.push(new Thing());
```

At this point, the structure looks like this:

```
rootThing
|
+--subThing
|  |
|  +--subThing
|  |
|  +--subThing
|  |
|  +--subThing
|
+--subThing
|
+--subThing
```

*So, how can I get a list of all the `subThing`s and all of **their** `subThing`s in `rootThing`?*

```
function getAllChildren(beginNode) {
    var allChildren = [];

    beginNode.subThings.forEach(function(childNode) {
        allChildren.push(childNode);
        // allChildren = allChildren.concat(childNode.subThings); // something along these lines
    });

    return allChildren;
}

console.log(getAllChildren(rootThing));
```

Comment: `console.dir( rootThing  )` :)

Comment: `console.log(JSON.stringify(rootThing, false, '  '))`

Comment: Imagine there is only one level and implement a function that prints the `thing` + its descendants. Then post it. If you do that we will show you how this function could be changed to be recursive in several keystrokes.

Comment: @BryceHanscomb now instead of `allChildren.push(childNode);` - return the `getAllChildren` called with `childNode`. And in the beginning of the function - initialize `allChildren` with `beginNode.subThings`

Answer (score 1):

With thanks to @zerkms, here is a working implementation:

```
function getAllChildren(beginNode) {
    var allChildren = beginNode.subThings;

    beginNode.subThings.forEach(function(childNode) {
        allChildren = allChildren.concat(getAllChildren(childNode));
    });

    return allChildren;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
var GetAllThings = function(Thing thing) {
    var result = [];

    //Assume you want to remove the subthings as you flatten
    var subthings = thing.subthings;
    thing.subThings = null;

    result.push(thing);

    for(var i = 0; i < subthings i++) {
        result.concat(GetAllThings(subthings[i]));
    }

    return result;
};
```

This will basically flatten the tree, but if you just want to see/process it, the above comments are correct in that you can just handle this as a json object.